# UnmarshalException InvalidClassException org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseTable

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I am developing an application with jpa 2 (EclipseLink), ejb 3 and PrimeFaces which is divided into jar (and jpa ejb) and a war, while attempting to deply I get this error:

```
Exception is: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Incoming message header or abbreviation processing   failed; nested exception is: java.io.InvalidClassException:    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseTable; Local class incompatible: stream serialVersionUID   = 7408378167056177847 classdesc, the local class serialVersionUID = -8,219,935,847,209,476,671 at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException (RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:121) at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke (Remote
```

Its clear to me that is a version of SERIAL error ID but how can I fix it ?? use Eclipse as ID.

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello solved the problem and would like to share with you, it took me one week to find the answer. I was using weblogic 10.3.5 to develop, even though I was using the same jars EclipseLink and javax.persistence that are within bea / modules to compile my project, it was not working. I uninstalled the server and install again thinking it could be a problem with the server but always got the same result. I also tried to embed the jars inside the application but neither worked. I migrated my weblogic server to version 10.3.6 and that was the answer, my application worked as it originally did not know why this problem occurred, but is fixed up version of the application server. Thank you very much to all who responded.

Answer (score 2):

You can try instructing WebLogic Server to prefer your bundled jars instead of its own. This can be done in `weblogic.xml` deployment descriptor, it would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
     <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
     </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

On second thought, persistence API is ejb jar dependency, and this setting works only for war module. So you could try with `weblogic-application.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application” 
xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
xsi:schemaLocation=”http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application 
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
   <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.*</package-name>        
   </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Comment: hello Predrag let me prove and i´ll inform u.. thanks 4 ur answer!!

Comment: i tried with <wls:container-descriptor>
      <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.*</wls:package-name>
      </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor> into weblogic.xml coz its a war.. but neither works :(

Comment: i tried also: <wls:context-root>ServiciosGeneralesWeb</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
      <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
      <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.*</wls:package-name>
      </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor> but its not working :(

Comment: Try removing `eclipselink.jar` from your `ear` prior to deploying, see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hello, i tried that also.. but its not working, even i rebuild the project into another eclipse without success, now im triying to install the application over weblogic 10.3.6... i will c what happens... this error got it with weblogic 10.3.5

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this type of error before, but my first thought would be that you have multiple versions of a similar jar.  Specifically it looks like,  org.eclipse.persistence -> javax.persistence.  It was probably serialized with one jar/class and de-serialized with another jar/class.

Typically in errors pertaining to J2EE containers and multiple jars, one jar/version exists in the application-containr, like weblogic, (maybe in endorsed directory) and the other is bundled with the application.

The solution if this is the case, is to not include the persistence jar with your application and delegate to the container.  If you are using maven/gradle, mark the artifact as `provided`

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply, my project is divided in an EJB that contains JPA model and in a WAR that contains the Web part, because in my job that's server architecture (two domains logic and web). I have a build.xml that builds my EJB that compiles the classes within the project including JPA, after rebuilding copy the local and remote interface to the web project (if i dont do that, it could fail to recognize the call on the Web). The first time I built the project had no trouble in fact I developed all the time so, but when I made a change was when he start to mark this.

Comment: I tried to compile the project exactly the same jars that exist in weblogic without success. I have also tried moving the interfaces and classes EJB model and put them (on the fly) to WAR and neither works.

Thanks for any help.

greetings.

Comment: @Mariah Is the `serialVersionUID` set statically or is it auto-generated?

Comment: in my model, all the JPA classes (entities) have :  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; this its put it by eclipse...